# Determining a value at a percentage point on an exponential curve

Tags: exponentiation, percentages

I have a device which is a certain amont on. When the device is 100% on it has the value `R`. When the device is 0% it has the value `0`. The curve of the device is exponential. I am trying to create a formula to represent this.

I am able to do this if I pick specific increments. For example, if I wanted to find the value for every 5% change I could do the following:

```
I: is the interval, 5 in this example...
P: is the percentage point I am at, e.g., 5, 10, 15, 20, etc...

(R^(100/I))^(P/I)
```

... the problem is that using this formula I need to know the increments before hand. A percentage could be anything...

How would I write a formula which I could use just R and P as inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple exponential curve with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(100) = R$ is 
$$f(P) = R \left( \frac{e^{P/100}-1}{e-1} \right)$$ 
where $P \in [0,100]$ is the percentage point.

Answer (score 0):

As you describe it the curve should be $f(P)=Rbe^{aP}$ where $a,b$ are parameters you want to estimate from your data.  You can take the log and get $\log (f(P))=\log R + \log b +aP$  If you take measurements of $P, f(P)$ you can fit this to a straight line.  If you measure $P$ from $0$ to $1$ and want $f(1)=R,$ then $b=e^{-a}$.  Excel has this capability built in.  Just list your data in neighboring column, plot and XY plot and add trendline.  The equations for doing this are in any numerical analysis test.  I like the discussion in [Numerical Recipes](http://numerical.recipes/).  Obsolete versions, with code, are free online

Comment: The formula yields $f(0) = R$, whereas the OP poses $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: @mlc: that is why $b$ is there, it lets us have $f(1)=R$ as requested.  I saw OP asked for $f(0)=0$ but the truly exponential curves don't go through $0$.  I commented on that.  We can let OP choose or tell us what is wrong with both our approaches.

Comment: Thanks guys. It technically `f(0)` isn't technically `0` but just about. I don't really understand `e` so I am going to have to read up on it. I will check out the links. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, I am not sure I like the `parameters you want to estimate from your data.`

Comment: The point is that this is a family of functions.  You indicated that you will collect data of the form $(P,f(P))$.  You can then use the parameters to make the curve fit the data as well as possible.  Then you get a function that you can feed new values of $P$ to and get a reasonable value for $f(P)$.  If the fit is not good, you need a different functional form.  It will probably also have parameters that you estimate from the data.  What do you think is wrong with that?

Comment: Maybe when you said an exponential function you meant polynomial, such as $f(P)=\sum a_nP^n$.  Again you can collect data and find a best fit polynomial of any degree you like.  Lower degrees will smooth out errors in your measurements.  Excel will do that for you as well.